# Ionic PickerController able to display images / icons?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, picker

So I made a simple picker controller displaying some information.

My question is if it's possible to display an image for the text values here.

For example, the following image I want to replace the item1, item2, etc with images from my assets folder.

Picker uses a string called "text" to display the value of text.

```
for (const d of this.Fridge){
  newInputs.push({
   text: d.text, //I want text: to display an image instead of a string
   value: {
   //Value I will get from selected item
   },
  checked: false
   })
}
```

[image]

```
async openPicker() {
var newInputs = [];

//Parse through all memebers in the loaded array from Firestore
for (const d of this.Fridge){
  newInputs.push({
    text: d.text, //I want text: to display an image instead of a string
    value: {
     //Value I will get from selected item
    },
    checked: false
  })
}
const picker = await this.pickerCtrl.create({
  buttons: [
{
  text: 'Cancel',
  handler: data => {
    console.log('Cancel'); 
      //update values here

      }
},
{
  text: 'Done',
  handler: data => {
    console.log('Done'); 
      //update values here

      }
},
],
  columns: [

    {
      name: '',
      options: newInputs
    },
  ],

});
await picker.present();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Instead, what you can do is to create custom picker using modal component and use ion-list to display image and text.

```
    <ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
      <ion-img [src]="item.src"></ion-img>
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <ion-label>{{item.text}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

[image]